# Create an XYZ tile using a WMS connection

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, wms, xyz-tiles

##### Overview

I am trying to create XYZ tiles (OSM Slippy Map standard) from a WMS source. A plausible way to do this, for a given zoom level, is to create a raster file from the WMS layer, and then use [`gdal2tiles.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html) with the [`--xyz`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal2tiles-xyz) flag. I would like to pursue a different route: creating the XYZ tiles one by one directly from the WMS source. I chose this option to avoid the need for the (usually large) intermediary raster file.

Below is a detailed description of an attempt which did not work. Below that is my question, hopefully clear on its own.

---

#### Step by step walkthrough

##### WMS

The [Italian Revenue Agency](https://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/portale/web/guest/schede/fabbricatiterreni/consultazione-cartografia-catastale/servizio-consultazione-cartografia) operates a publicly accessible WMS:

> https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php

I can add this to QGIS and observe the requests sent via the Network Logger:

[image]

An example request:

```
199360 GET https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?language=ita&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=701407.8201069784118,4696470.658466426656,701958.4807777189417,4697083.337434036657&CRS=EPSG:25832&WIDTH=802&HEIGHT=892&LAYERS=Cartografia_Catastale,copyright,vestizioni,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province,copyright,vestizioni,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province,Cartografia_Catastale&STYLES=,,,,,,,,,default,default,,,default,default,default,default,default,default,default,default,default&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=72&MAP_RESOLUTION=72&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:72&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

##### XYZ tiles

To download the data for a certain XYZ tile, I need to have the boundaries of that tile. The python function `get_tile_centres` below takes the zoom level, X and Y grid coordinates of a tile, and outputs the centre of that tile in EPSG:3857.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.wkt

maxc = gpd.GeoSeries(shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(180 0)"),crs=4326).to_crs(3857).iloc[0].xy[0][0]

sidelength = lambda z: 2*maxc/(2**z)
def get_tile_centres(z,x,y):
    # return coordinates of tile centres in EPSG:3857
    x = -maxc+maxc/(2**z)+sidelength(z)*x
    y = maxc-maxc/(2**z)-sidelength(z)*y
    return x, y
```

This image nicely displays tile boundaries at Z=3:

[image]

Using the image, `get_tile_centres(3,4,1)` (outputs: `2504688.542848654, 12523442.714243278`) should send us to somewhere between Mainland Norway and Svalbard. Indeed it does:

[image]

As a start, I create the boundaries of a specific tile. I chose `16/34852/24230`. I do:

```
import numpy as np
points=[]
for i in [[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,-1],[-1,1],[1,1]]:
    points.append(
        np.array(get_tile_centres(16,34852,24230))-np.array([i[0]*sidelength(16)/2,i[1]*sidelength(16)/2])
    )
gpd.GeoSeries(
    shapely.geometry.Polygon([list(point) for point in points]),crs=3857
).to_file("tile_16_34852_24230.geojson")
```

To check that this is indeed correct, I create (using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)) an EPSG:4326 version of  `tile_16_34852_24230.geojson` so I can create an `mbtiles` file using [`tippecanoe`](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe).

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 tile_16_34852_24230_EPSG4326.geojson tile_16_34852_24230.geojson
tippecanoe -o tile_16_34852_24230.mbtiles --force tile_16_34852_24230_EPSG4326.geojson -z6 -z16
```

I observe the result using [`mbview`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbview) (`mbview tile_16_34852_24230.mbtiles`). The tile boundaries (red lines) nicely align with the sides of my rectangle (green):

[image]

##### Query WMS for specific XYZ tile

To download the data for tile `16/34852/24230`, I observe the requests via the Network Logger. I need the bounding box coordinates in `EPSG:25832`. I construct a URL the following way:

```
import pyproj

src_crs = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:3857")
tgt_crs = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:25832")
transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(src_crs, tgt_crs)

x, y = get_tile_centres(16,34852,24230)
sidelength(16)

xmax = x+sidelength(16)/2
xmin = x-sidelength(16)/2

ymin = y-sidelength(16)/2
ymax = y+sidelength(16)/2

xmin, ymin = transformer.transform(xmin, ymin)
xmax, ymax = transformer.transform(xmax, ymax)

URL = \
f"https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?language=ita&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX={xmin:.09f},{ymin:.09f},{xmax:.09f},{ymax:.09f}&CRS=EPSG:25832&WIDTH=793&HEIGHT=793&LAYERS=Cartografia_Catastale,Cartografia_Catastale,copyright,vestizioni,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province,copyright,vestizioni,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province&STYLES=,default,,,,,,,,,default,default,,,default,default,default,default,default,default,default,default&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=72&MAP_RESOLUTION=72&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:72&TRANSPARENT=TRUE"
```

`URL` is: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?language=ita&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=701464.098518356,4696543.867341996,701903.229444590,4697007.387665750&CRS=EPSG:25832&WIDTH=793&HEIGHT=793&LAYERS=Cartografia_Catastale,Cartografia_Catastale,copyright,vestizioni,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province,copyright,vestizioni,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,simbolo_graffa,codice_plla,fabbricati,CP.CadastralParcel,strade,acque,CP.CadastralZoning,province&STYLES=,default,,,,,,,,,default,default,,,default,default,default,default,default,default,default,default&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=72&MAP_RESOLUTION=72&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:72&TRANSPARENT=TRUE. (I load this to environment variable `$URL`).

After creating the directory `xyz_test/16/34852`, I do:

```
curl -o xyz_test/16/34852/24230.png $URL
```

Observe result:

[image]

Adding [WMS](https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php) & and the above created `tile_16_34852_24230.geojson`, I observe how the tile `16/34852/24230` should look like:

[image]

The area within the red square, and the png above look similar, that's encouraging. Adding 16/34852/24230.png as an XYZ layer as well:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**As mostly visible in the top left & bottom right, the tile is a bit off. Agreement with the WMS source is quite good in the top right and bottom left corner.**

##### Attempted fix

The WMS response data is supposed to be viewed in EPSG:25832, but I am viewing it XYZ tiles, assuming EPSG:3857. I convert the png to a georeferenced tiff file (using [`gdal_translate`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)):

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:25832 -a_ullr 701464.098518356 4697007.387665750 701903.229444590 4696543.867341996 xyz_test/16/34852/24230.png xyz_test/16/34852/24230.tif
```

(I got the numbers for the `-a_ullr` from the URL above.) TIFF now perfectly aligns with underlying WMS layer, but not with the XYZ tile boundaries:

[image]
[image]

This is worrying, because I planned to create the EPSG:3857 png from this tif, and part of the area I would like to cover (red square) is not covered by the tif (white area in top left & bottom right corners). I create a png to observe result (using [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)):

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 xyz_test/16/34852/24230.tif xyz_test/16/34852/24230_EPSG3857.png
```

Output:

```
Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Creating output file that is 793P x 837L.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Adding it to QGIS

[image]

Result without underlying WMS layer:

[image]

Result with WMS layer:

[image]

Tile is visible off in all corners, this fix did not work.

---

#### Question

Given a WMS service, queryable using bounding boxes in EPSG:25832, how can I use it to create a png for a given XYZ tile?

Same question asked in a different way: what did go wrong in my attempt, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps get MapProxy (https://mapproxy.org/) to do it for you

Comment: Change the projection in the WMS url to 3857 and use the unprojected tile bounds to fetch the image.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks, I tried, instead of a png I get an xml, containing (among other things) `<ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">`. If I go to the GetCapabilities page of the WMS: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?language=ita&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities, I find a number of EPSGs listed, but 3857 is not among them unfortunately.

Comment: @nmtoken, good idea, looking into that.

Comment: cascade through GeoServer if MapProxy can't handle it - you need to reproject a bigger area and then clip to make it work anyway

Comment: I haven't yet been able to establish if MapProxy can do it or not; I describe my attempt here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456815/how-to-load-wms-info-to-an-xyz-tile-using-mapserver.